# Accept only number formats for a property from JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, number-formatting, jsonserializer

I am developing ASP.Net Web API application and we are exposing a REST API for different clients. I have a problem when taking users' JSON files and converting them to Data Model classes. My JSON looks like below.

```
{"engagementid":1,"clientname":"fsdfs","myno":"23,45","address1":"fsd","address2":"fsdfs","city":"fsdfs","zip":"fsdf","info":"fsdfs","country":"fsdfs","currency":"NOK"}
```

You can see that my "myno" is sent as a string. But in my Server Data Model "myno" is a double value. So what happen here is when I send the value for "myno" as "23,45", it gets assigned to MyNo property of my Model as 2345. This is wrong, because you can see that the number has been changed because of this wrong conversion. What I simply need is to restrict this conversion. I mean, I want to send an error to Client if he sends a string for "myno" property. Since it is a double value in my Server Data Model, I want to accept only numbers from the client for this property. Which means, I want it like this.

```
{"myno":2345} //correct
{"myno":"2345"} //wrong. I want to send a error to user by saying, "We only accept Numbers for this value"
```

How do I do this?

Update:
This problem gets solved if I am using int in my server-model. I mean, if a client send a string to a property which is represented as int in my model, then it gives an error to user by saying string to int conversion can not be done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't whether it is correct or not. I am just telling my suggestion according to my experience. Why can't you create a custom validation attribute and check the datatype of data.

```
public class IsNumberAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
       if(value.GetType() != Int)
          return new ValidationResult("Only Numbers Allowed");
        return null;
    }
}
```